# Where can I got a description/man page on return call in C?

Tags: c, linux, manpage

I'm trying to get a man-page for the *return* call in C programming language but nothing appropriate installed on my system(GNU/Linux Debian). Where should I look for documentation?

Comment: It's not a system call it's a [language construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement). Look it up in your favorite C book, it is probably covered in the first few chapters.

Comment: It is called a _return value_

Comment: @self um, rather a *return statement…*

Comment: Any C reference will work. I recommend the [K&R C book](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_C_Programming_Language.html?id=161QAAAAMAAJ).

Comment: BTW,what is so special about the `return` statement---never imagined anything special!

Comment: @shekharsuman For example in C++ `return` can create temporary objects, so yes it is not always straight forward. (and yes I know the OP asked for C)

Comment: @PeterM-Same in Java too...

Comment: It is clear to me that is nothing special in the _return_ statement, but for the sake of curiosity I like to read man pages.. and was surprised that it was nothing about _return_ there.. _return_ takes a parameter and I think minimal description should be..

Comment: @PeterM, this is less commonly known, but in C this can happen, too.

Comment: Man pages are for system/library calls. `return` is a language construct. What you are asking for is like asking far a man page for the plus (`+`) arithmetic operator.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "man page" because `return` is a C language keyword not a *function*; you cannot *call* `return`; it is simply an instruction to *exit* a function and return to the point *after* the call to that function.

Anyway, the documentation for return is in the language definition.  Any documentation, reference or tutorial for C will explain it.  For example http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return.

Answer (score 0):

You can find nice HTML and PDF versions of C89, C99, and C11 here:

http://port70.net/~nsz/c/

There is also GNU C Library:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html